# Assigning to strided subsets of vectors

Tags: c++, matlab, vector

Say I have two vectors like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > A(2, std::vector<double>(6));
std::vector<double> B(3);
```

In Matlab I can define `A` as follows:

```matlab
A(1, 1:2:end) = B;
A(2, 2:2:end) = B;
```

This has the effect of assigning the elements of `B` first to `A[0][0]`, `A[0][2]`, `A[0][4]`, and then to `A[1][1]`, `A[1][3]`, `A[1][5]`. For example, if `B` is `{1, 4, 9}`, then `A` would be:

```
{ { 1, 0, 4, 0, 9, 0, } ,
  { 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 9, } }
```

Is there any way to do this in C++ without a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) instead:

```
std::valarray<std::valarray<double>> A(std::valarray<double>(6), 2);
std::valarray<double> B{ 1, 4, 9 };
A[0][std::slice(0,B.size(),2)] = B;
A[1][std::slice(1,B.size(),2)] = B;
```

Output:

```
1   0   4   0   9   0   
0   1   0   4   0   9
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86d17f76e18932ef)

Comment: Really interesting post on `valarray`!